# How to create the layout like android contacts favorite

Tags: android

How to create the Layout like the (Android ICS Contacts Favorite layout )image i attached

[image: Layout with image and overlay name]

am using the grid view for creating the layout for the photos grid. Thats perfectly working. But

how can i create the overlay layout like the black transparent with name or image ?? any one guide me to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `FrameLayout`. It puts contents on each other.

Comment: ... you can look into android source ...

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/master/res/layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (Note: this is the Custom XML Layout for the `GridView` that will be setup in the `Adapter`)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="11sp" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And it will look this:

[image]

*This is **as-is** from one of my apps.* Play around with the `android:layout_width` and the `android:layout_height` to set your own size. Also, fiddle with this `android:background="#50000000"` attribute to get it looking as you please. The **50** in it is the *alpha* that will set the transparency.